# convert Promise based function to an observable based function

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, observable

What is the simplest way to do something like this in an observable approach way?

```
async function promiseBased {
    await // wait for some jobs to be done
}

await promisebased();
// then do other jobs
```

Comment: IMO This is too broad. Please may you narrow it down?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have an async function which I want to wait for its job be finished and then doing other jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a little more I end up with this approach which I'm not sure be the simplest one:

```
function observableBased() {
    return Observable.create((observable) => {
        // some async jobs
        // then
        observable.next();
    })
}


observableBased().subscriber(()=>{
    // do other jobs
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observable.fromPromise to get an observable to promise and observable.toPromise to get a promise from an observable

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it is what you're looking for, but there's a built in operator to transform a promise to an observable

```
var result = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(yourPromiseFunction());
result.subscribe(el => console.log(el));
```

link to [doc](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise)

Comment: I don't want to use promise anymore but I want to do what I used to do with promise, now with observable.